# How can I put a button and the tab navigator at the same page?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-tabnavigator

I am a beginner of react-native

I just opened a project with tab navigator already exist

I want to add a button to my search screen

How can I do that?

I tried to look for some instruction online

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
Home: HomeScreen,
Search: SearchScreen,
},
{
initialRouteName: 'Home',
}
);

 const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

 export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return <AppContainer />;
 }
 }
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>         

 this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')}>
          <Text>
            Search
          </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```
export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({

Main: MainTabNavigator,


}));
```

**App.js**

```
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
      <AppNavigator />
    </View>
  );
```

where should I add the RootStack to ?
Thank you for answering.

Comment: id don't see any thing about  tabNavigator in your codes

Comment: They are build inside the MainTabNavigator

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code?

App.js:

```js
const Switch = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({

Main: MainTabNavigator,


}));


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
Home: HomeScreen,
Search: SearchScreen,
Switch: Switch
},
{
initialRouteName: 'Switch',
}
);

 const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

 export default AppContainer;
```